Python project with flask doesn't think I have a email column for some reason
I've been trying to follow this tutorial but I changed my code slightly to understand better, but I'm getting a error that there is a missing column when I'm trying to create a new resource via a post request, I'm utilizing flask, flask_restful and flask_alchemy
Model definition:
class UserModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User(name={name}, email={email})"

User class definition:
# user class
class User(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields_user)
    def get(self, user_id):
        result = UserModel.query.get(id=user_id)
        return {"request_type": "get", "data": result}
    
    # @marshal_with(resource_fields_user)
    def post(self):
        args = user_post_args.parse_args()
        user = UserModel(name=args["name"], email=args["email"])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        
        return {"request_type": "post", "data": user}, 201

The post request:
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/users' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "email": "jh@testing.com"
}'

But when I run a post to this I get the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user_model has no column named email [SQL: INSERT INTO user_model (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)] [parameters: ('Jane Doe', 'jh@testing.com')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

Trying to figure out why it thinks that I don't have an email column?

Any chance db.create_all() did not run?
https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/quickstart/#create-the-tables
